# mysqli_connect() mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): No such file or directory error when calling from other php file

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm having a bit of a weird one here and unable to find the cause on web search.

I have a `functions.php` file which contains the following code:

```
function random_color_part() {
    return str_pad( dechex( mt_rand( 0, 255 ) ), 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
}

function random_html_color() {
    return random_color_part() . random_color_part() . random_color_part();
}

function unique_random_colors($sql) {
    $link2 = mysqli_connect($DB_HOST, $DB_USER, $DB_PASS) or die(mysqli_connect_error());
    mysqli_select_db($link2, $RMV_DB) or die(mysqli_error($link2));

    $m = array();
    if ($query = mysqli_prepare($link2, $sql)) {

        mysqli_stmt_execute($query);
        mysqli_stmt_bind_result($query, $user_id);

        while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($query)) {
            $m[$user_id] = random_html_color();
        }
    } else {
        return FALSE;
    }
    mysqli_close($link2);
    return $m;
}
```

In another file, let's call it `main.php`:

```
<?php
require_once('functions.php');
$link = mysqli_connect($DB_HOST, $DB_USER, $DB_PASS) or die(mysqli_connect_error());
$my_stmt = 'SELECT DISTINCT user FROM articles_discussion WHERE article='.mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_GET['aid']);
print_r(unique_random_colors($my_stmt);
mysqli_close($link);
```

but I get the error `mysqli_connect() mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): No such file or directory` and it says this is happening on the line in function `unique_random_colors` that reads `$link2 = mysqli_connect($DB_HOST, $DB_USER, $DB_PASS) or die(mysqli_connect_error());`

Why would it tell me a file or directory doesn't exist? If I copy and paste the function code into a standalone file and run it with a few modifications just to make it syntactically correct, it works fine. As soon as I try and call it from `functions.php` it gives the error.

Comment: Where are you initialising `$DB_HOST`, etc.? How are you passing those into your functions? Why are you creating a new connection to your database in a function when you already have one? Why not just pass that in?

Comment: Please check if credentials are working for mysql.

Comment: Yes, credentials are all working and I'm initializing `$DB_HOST` etc at the very top of functions.php, so the function should have access to them, right?

I'm creating a new connection in the function because I don't want to have to pass it in under a variable.

Answer (score 0):

Check your mysqli connection variable that your are passing correct value or not.
Best practice that never use dynamic value inside the function value.

Make a another file for only connection DB and include it in your file. There you can test that your connection is working or not.